# MySQL COUNT query not responding

Tags: mysql, count, query-optimization

I'm performing a table cleanup with a limit, but before wanted to check the count.

simple count() query is not responding.

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM schema.table1 INNER JOIN schema.table2 ON table1.col1 = table2.col2;
```

The table might have more than 50 million records. I know the impact of adding a join in such a large dataset. But, that is required to cleanup the data not matching with the other table.

Any guidance would be appreciated. Or alternative approach.

Comment: For an alternative approach - If it's cleanup, perhaps you can sacrifice efficiency for practicality. Are CPU minutes worth more than engineer hours? It might take 100 times longer to run if you write the hard part in your application code rather than mashing it into a query, but a big ol' loop will get there in the end without connection timeouts and memory exhaustion. If you keep track of how far you've got, if anything does go wrong you can restart where you left off.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't much that can be done to optimize your query, other than to add indices which cover the join conditions:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx1 ON schema.table1 (col1);
CREATE INDEX idx2 ON schema.table2 (col2);
```

You may run `EXPLAIN` before and after the above step to get a better understanding of how MySQL is executing the query.

Comment: these are mapping tables with 3 - 4 columns.

Comment: This information doesn't change my answer.

Comment: let me try with explain, why it's taking time to return. Not sure indexing will take how much time. Only reason why this table is not indexed, due to frequent insertions.

Comment: If you can't index, then there is no good way to know the count.  Maybe you could make some kind of estimate using MySQL's statistics.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Let me try.